# Problem after onShouldStartLoadWithRequest returned false on react-native-webview

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

In my React-Native project i use react-native-webview, actually i use onShouldStartLoadWithRequest to verify url requests. When url is equals  my variable, the onShouldStartLoadWithRequest return true and load url normally, but, when url equals my variable i display alert and onShouldStartLoadWithRequest return false.
On alert  when user click in ok i navigate from my app login page, but if user cancel and stay on page the webview dont load others urls ontened of page anymore
Basically, it's as if after returning false to a url, onShouldStartLoadWithRequest didn't load any other

**My code:**

```
function verifyurl(url) {

    
    if (url == myvarUrl) {
      alerta();
      return false;
    } else {
      setNewUrl(url)
      return true;
    }
  }

  async function alerta() {
    const response = await alert();
    response && logOut();
  }


  //Verifica se existe item na pilha navegação e retira
  function logOut() {
    let canGoBack = navigation.canGoBack();
    canGoBack ? navigation.goBack() : console.log('AGIU MAIS DE UMA VEZ');
  }

  /* ========================> Retorno de Visualização <======================== */

  const Spinner = () => (
    <View style={genericStyles.activityContainer}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#f29900" />
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <View style={genericStyles.containerWebView}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor={genericStyles.colors.BlueBg} barStyle={'light-content'} />
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: propriedade }}
        ref={webViewRef}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback
        javaScriptEnabled
        scalesPageToFit
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid
        useWebkit
        startInLoadingState={true}
        cacheEnabled={false}
        renderLoading={Spinner}
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(event) => {
          return verifyurl(event.url)
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
```

**Development environment**

```
react: ^17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: ^0.68.2 => 0.68.2
react-native-webview: 11.22.2
```

Please Help me!

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?